# Select cell value from row based on value in another column in Pandas with Python

Tags: python, pandas

How can I get a value from a cell based on a value of another cell of the same row? For example, let's say I have the following dataframe:

```
    A     C   D
0  foo1    0   0
1  foo2    2   4
2  foo3    9   8
3  foo4    6  12
4  foo5    7  14
```

How can I grab the value from column C of the row that has foo3 in column A? In this example, it is 9. I am using Pandas with Python.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html

Comment: google search before asking

Comment: Do you think tagging this python2.7 will give you a different answer than tagging it in python?

Comment: `df.at[df['A'].eq('foo3').idxmax(),'C']`